# eventDragStop not showing new time - FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I've got a calendar day view in which users are able to add events by dragging items (like the demo shown here: http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.1/demos/external-dragging.html).

When the user has dragged the event onto the calender, that fires all of the relevant callbacks correctly and the calender refreshes and works as expected. If the user wishes to resize the event, that also works correctly too.

The one case I have left is if the user drags the whole event and drops it elsewhere in the calendar. I want it at this stage to fire of the callbacks and update my database. However, when I console.log or alert the event data on the `eventDragStop` callback, it shows the old date/time of the event, rather than the new date/time that the user has dragged it too. The calender displays the event correctly in the view - but when I refresh it, it seems nothing has changed as this callback isn't sending the updated date/time.

Any ideas? I'm stumped!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should have the updates etc in callback `eventDrop` , not in eventDragStop